# Unix/Bash Iterate over two variables over sliding windows in a sequence of numbers

Tags: bash, loops, unix

Using unix/bash, I need to run a command-line program "program" that requires as input an integer i and an integer j as parameter values for -L and -H, respectively:

```
program -L i -H j
```

Using a loop I need to iterate over a sequence of values using variables i and j, something like seq(i 10 j), from 1 to 1000, with a step size of 10. So in a for loop, the program would execute like this:

```
program -L 1 -H 10
program -L 11 -H 20
program -L 21 -H 30
program -L 31 -H 40
program -L 41 -H 50
...
program -L 991 -H 1000
```

I want the results in file, `results.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a C-style for loop. Something like

```sh
for (( n = 10; n <= 1000; n += 10 )); do
    program -L "$(( n - 9 ))" -H "$n"
done > results.txt
```

Comment: You may want to tell the OP that if `program` doesn't emit its arguments, then emitting them with the `for` loop would assist the person who later reads `results.txt`, thereby distinguishing each execution's output.

Comment: Yes @JeffHolt, this is a good idea ! Thank you